# Selecting multiple divs in html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do we hover over multiple div in html at the same time?

I have two divs at different positions in a html page.

I want to hover on any of divs and it, and the other div to get selected.

How can I accomplish it using preferably css properties only?
currently its going from parent to child not the vice versa,i tried all different combinations. even ~ and + properties.

html code:

```
<div id=one1>
<div id=two2></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#one1:hover { background-color: yellow;}
#two2:hover { background-color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Without some HTML, this is nearly impossible to answer absolutely

Comment: You say CSS but you've tagged jQuery as well. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: do not be so harsh. There is no need for code example here as you can see on the great answers

Comment: @mplungjan - they are assumptions (albeit ones which may be correct) not answers, given we have no knowledge of the OPs code

Comment: Two divs at different positions - hover one = hover the other. What code do we need to see?

Comment: Please post some HTML so we can re-open this question. It is really too simple to even need HTML but the purists have spoken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you mean something like this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h944n/)**

```
#one:hover ~ #two , 
#one:hover ~ #three  
{ background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Thanks. Trying to learn, I am still in learning phase :)

Comment: In this example why isnt your original div also changing the colour?
on hovering over the 1st div it should also change colour to yellow.

Comment: @Richa Instead of answering my query you need not comment on my css abilities!!

Comment: @Richa so if can can help with the desired solution then please help me out.

Comment: @GyaneshGouraw If you want to change color of original div as well then do this http://jsfiddle.net/h944n/19/. Hope this solves it

Comment: @GyaneshGouraw If it helps don't forget to accept it as answer :)

Comment: I will happily accept your "answer"
but my problem is that
you have 2 divs,u hover onto one ,both the divs get highlighted,then you hover onto another both the divs get highlighted.
but in your case only first part is happening !!
can u get me a solution for that.

Comment: @GyaneshGouraw I updated your question as you should have. Please modify if I missed out on something

Comment: +1 Congrats for the upcoming badge ;) *Just for fun:* In Webkit-based browsers I'd go with `#one:hover ~ :-webkit-any(#two, #three) { background-color: yellow; }` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/h944n/38/)**

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks. And Nice addition to answer ,very useful for myself too:)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a structure similar to the one below, all you have do is add specific styles to the child `div` on `.parent:hover`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent:hover .child{your style goes here}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jquery Solution using `toggleClass`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('green');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
}

.green {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umTm4/1/)